# Mysql Node.js query fails but works in workbench

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm getting the callback error 'Incorrect parameters in the call to native function \'json_object\' for the below query in node.js but the same query works when I try it out in the mysql workbench?

```
SELECT t1.typeId AS typeId,
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.hour) AS hour,
t2.userInfo AS userInfo
FROM UserCommits t1
INNER JOIN (   SELECT  t1.id AS id,
JSON_OBJECT("id", t1.id,
"name", t1.name,
"birthUnix", UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.birthDate),
"gender", t1.gender,
"image", t2.secure_url,
"connectionInfo", t3.connectionInfo) AS userInfo
FROM Users t1
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT userId,
secure_url
FROM UserProfileImages
WHERE id IN (
SELECT MAX(id)
FROM UserProfileImages
GROUP BY userId
)
) t2
ON t1.id = t2.userId
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT connectionId,
JSON_OBJECT(
"id", id,
"createdUnix", UNIX_TIMESTAMP(createdDt)
) AS connectionInfo
FROM UserConnections
WHERE userId = 98
) t3
ON t1.id = t3.connectionId
) t2
ON t1.userId = t2.id
WHERE t1.locationId = 41
```

Comment: please show also your js code

Comment: Thanks nbk fixed the issue with a group by statement below

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue..

To insert a JSON_Object from a subquery into another JSON_Object there mysql checks that there is a 1 to 1 relationship.  I fixed the issue by updating the subquery to include a Group By statement on the join column.

```
(
    SELECT connectionId,
           JSON_OBJECT(
               "id", id,
               "createdUnix", UNIX_TIMESTAMP(createdDt)
           ) AS connectionInfo
    FROM UserConnections
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT MAX(id)
        FROM UserConnections
        WHERE userId = ${ownerId}
        GROUP BY connectionId
    )
           )
```